# How to pass an optional parameter in link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link like:

```
<%= link_to 'something', some_path(:param1 => something, :param2 => something) %>
```

How can I make param2 optional? I want to include it based on a condition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

**Approach 1**

```
<%= link_to 'something', some_path(
  {:param1 => something}.merge((x==1) ? {:param2 => something} : {}) %>
```

**Approach 2**

```
<%= link_to 'something', some_path(:param1 => 1, :param2 => (2 if x==1)) %>
```

In the above example when x equals to 1, the `param2` key value is nil. The `link_to` method ignores the `nil` valued keys.

Comment: I noticed `@MrRuru` suggested approach 2 before me.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this:

```
<%= link_to 'something', some_path(:param1 => 'something', :param2 => ('something else' if some_condition)) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you to use a hash here if there is many condition based options:

```
<% params = {}
   params[:param1] => "blah-blah" if condition
   params[:param2] => "blah-blah" if condition
   params[:param3] => "blah-blah" if condition
   params[:param4] => "blah-blah" if condition
   params[:param5] => "blah-blah" if condition %>
<%= link_to 'something', some_path(params) %>
```

It is good idea to wrap it as a helper